# How to detect and catch "connection time out" in PHP with Salesforce integration

Tags: php, salesforce, integration

I use Salesforce API Webservices to create/update records through Php. I test I would end up get a message coming back from Salesforce saying "cant connect to host", so I suspect that is what most of my users are expecting when the php script fails on them.

I believe I try catch and exception but It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `Could not connect to host` means it is not able to connect to Salesforce (or some other server you're integrating with). Make sure you have the correct URL.